# Android startActivity with intent doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-event

i have a countDownTimer , and it fisish the time i want to go to an error screen
this is the code for countDownTimer

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(36000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODOAuto-generated method stub
                remaingTimer.setText(millisUntilFinished + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated methodstub
                Intent goToMainTabs = new Intent(
                        "com.localizedbasedcompetition.FINISHTIME");
                startActivity(goToMainTabs);
            }
        };
```

i want to go to finishtime activity , and this is the code for finishtime activity

```
public class FinishTime extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    Button backToMain;
    TextView errorMessage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.finishtime);
        initialize();
    }
    private void initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        backToMain= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bFinishTimeBackToMain);
        errorMessage=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tvFinishTime);
        backToMain.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bFinishTimeBackToMain:
            Intent goToMainTabs = new Intent(
                    "com.localizedbasedcompetition.MAINTABS");
            startActivity(goToMainTabs);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the mainfest for finishtime activity

```
<activity
            android:name=".FinishTime"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.localizedbasedcompetition.FINISHTIME" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

my problem is when the countDownTimer finish counting , i  got an excpetion , what am i doing wrong?

### This is the exception

```
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.localizedbasedcompetition/com.localizedbasedcompetition.FinishTime}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at com.localizedbasedcompetition.FinishTime.initialize(FinishTime.java:24)
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at com.localizedbasedcompetition.FinishTime.onCreate(FinishTime.java:19)
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-23 14:16:14.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: I suspect you need to call super.onFinish() in you onFinish definition.

Comment: Also, paste your Logcat content so we can see what exception you are getting and what is causing it.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel do u mean i have to make `super.onFinish()` ? but this method desn't exist

Comment: @KazekageGaara i will past what you need

Comment: sorry... early in the morning and I misread the question :)

Comment: another (probably wrong) thought... does the timer need to be started? I don't see you invoking it anywhere, just defining it. It doesn't start by itself simply by being defined, does it?

Comment: Intent goToMainTabs = new Intent(ActivityName.this,"com.localizedbasedcompetition.FINISHTIME"); ??? u need context.

Comment: @iNan, no, that's actually correct. You don't need context when you use the intent name.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel the timer starts but i didn't show you that and the timer works good , my problem is when the timer finsish

Comment: Hey errorMessage is TextView or Button it is throwing error

Comment: @iNan error Message is textview

Comment: change errorMessage=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tvFinishTime);
 to errorMessage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvFinishTime); in initialize.

Comment: From your logcat content, it seems you are attempting to cast one type into another uncompatible type. Show your XML as well please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call start() on the CountDownTimer. Otherwise it's not doing anything.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

and according to your exception you have defined something as a `TextView` in your XML that you are accidentally casting to something else (is that your `Button` cast?) impossible to tell without seeing the xml, but that's what the exception is. Make sure you refer to your Views correctly in the Java as you've defined them in the XML.

oh, and as iNan points out, clean your project just in case after you've fixed. Eclipse has a nasty way of not updating things like this from time to time.

Comment: i did that really , but i didn't show you that , my problem is when the timer finish counting , i can see the timer working and prints on the screen the remaining time every 1 seconds , but when there is no remaining time , the timer calls the finish methods , and here i got the exception , i updated the question with the exception

Comment: see my edit, and then give me the green checkmark, and welcome to Stack! :)

Comment: yes man , errorMessage is textView but i cast it to button :)thank you

Comment: most welcome! The stack trace is a really good place to look for what the problem is :)

Comment: the exception. that's what it's called